# What is the threshold of engagement that determines an active community?

Tags: user-engagement

Is there a metric that defines a difference between an engaged community versus content produced locally by the agent? What is a good protocol for scaling up and scaling down when the threshold on interaction changes? I notice that Stack Exchange uses Beta labelling when scaling up.

Answer (score 1):

Every community's going to be different

For some, it could be 100s of 1000s of posts per day

For others, it might be 1-2 emails a month

Your threshold should be relative to at least all of the following:

- interest of community members (observationally, only about 10% will "participate")
- size of community (a community of 20's going to look quite different than a community of 20,000)
- availability of community members to "participate"
- ease of "participation" (ie, how much friction is there between thinking, "I want to share this" to "here, community, have a share")

I used to comanage an IRL-and-mailing-list-and-Facebook-group tech group

When I started attending (a couple years prior to trying to help it keep going), we'd have ~15-20 folks at each meetup, and at least a few emails per week, and a few group posts

By the time I moved to help run it, we were down to *maybe* 6 people at a meetup...more often 3, and we called it quits after it hung around that number for a year